# CircuiTikZ and FET drawing

Tags: latex, tikz

Is there some simple way to avoid shorting the pins of a FET?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0)
    to[I,I=$I_s$] (0,2) % The current source
    to[short] (2,2);
    \draw (2,0)
    to node[nigfete]{FET} (2,2) % The FET transistor
    to[short] (2,0) to[short] (0,0);
    \draw (2,2)
    to[short] (4,2)
    to[R=$R$] (4,0)
    to[short] (2,0);
    \draw (4,2);
    \draw node[rground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make a sketch of the changes you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to understand what you want to achieve, but

- use `short` only if you need to add poles or labels, otherwise `--` is easier to type;
- use the anchors of the components.
- `tikz` is automatically loaded by `circuitikz`, and that one has a mandatory argument (the voltage direction standard, look at the manual and at the wanings! ;-).

So a first change could be this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=4pt] {standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[rground]{}
    to[I,I=$I_s$] (0,2) -- (2,2)
    node[nigfete, anchor=D](F){FET}  % The FET transistor
    (F.S) to[short, -*] (2,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw (2,2) -- (4,2)
    to[R=$R$] (4,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw node[rground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

then, in my opinion, it would be better to use relative positioning to make the circuit relocatable.

If you need/want the FET centered in the branch it could be better to start with it or use the `calc` Ti*k*Z library (already loaded by `circuitikz`). In the following circuit all the movement are relative, so you can move it by just changing the first `(0,0)`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=4pt] {standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node[rground](GND){} to[I,I=$I_s$] ++(0,2)
    -- ++(2,0) coordinate(top)
    -- ++(2,0) to[R=$R$] ++(0,-2)
    -- (GND-|top) coordinate(bottom)
    -- (GND)
    ($(top)!0.5!(bottom)$) node[nigfete](F){FET}
    (F.D) -- (top) (F.S) -- (bottom);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want. I simply inserted FET node in place of another component C, where no similar distinction is needed.

Comment: Yes, the distinction between node-type and path-type components is quite central to `circuitikz`. Happy of being of help!